# How to print the value of a variable in the stack trace

Tags: python

I want to print in the stack trace the value of a variable.

Indeed, when executing my program, I have an error and I would like to know the value of a variable.

I don't have access to the console.

---

code:

```
os.chdir(directoryName)
```

Error:

> os.chdir(directoryName) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '' »

Comment: can you share your code and the error..!

Comment: Brilliant question, can't get why no-one has asked it before!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try to declare a custom exception for debugging value.

```
class DebuggingValueError(Exception):
    """Exception raised for debugging value.

    Attributes:
        value -- input value which caused the error
        message -- explanation of the error
    """

    def __init__(self, value, message="this value is for debugging"):
        self.value= value
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)
```

2. try to catch this exception in the outside of program.

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
try:
    os.chdir(directoryName)
    ....
    ....
    ....
except Exception as ex:
  logging.exception(ex)
  logging.debug(directoryName)
```

Comment: I tried this: 
```
    try:
        os.chdir("coucou")
    except Exception as ex:
        #logging.exception(ex)
        logging.debug("AZERTYUIOKJHGFD")#directoryName)
```
but `"AZERTYUIOKJHGFD"` is not printed.

Comment: @Colas you might have to config logging to output into stdout in your terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

NOTE! Be careful of inadvertently logging PII/sensitive data!

1. https://github.com/andy-landy/traceback_with_variables also looks excellent! Following on,

```
from traceback_with_variables import prints_exc


@prints_exc
def f(n):
    print(1 / n)


def main():
    f(0)


main()
```

2. Another option is given here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178112/1021819

Copying from there (thanks CadentOrange!),

```
import sys, traceback, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

try: 
    x = 0 
    y = 1 
    z = y / x 
    z = z + 1 
    print "z=%d" % (z) 
except: 
    logging.exception("Values at Exception: x=%d y=%d " % (x,y))
```

i.e. `logging.exception()` gives access to the variables defined within the `try` block.